# How to determine exactly how much gas is needed for deploying a smart contract before deployment?

Tags: contract-development, contract-deployment

I want to determine exaclty how much gas is needed to deoploy a smart contract. there is a `estimateGas()` in Web3 api, and also properties with same name in solc output. but why **estimate**? as far as I know for every opcode there is a fixed gas needed to execute and also for using storage (all well defined). logically, It seems to me that the amount of gas needed for deploying a smart contract is deterministic and can be exactly known before deployment (in the case of the gas consumed in constructor function we can find out the gas usage by running it in a local EVM).

am I right or I am missing something? if yes, How?

Comment: When you deploy a contract the constructor is executed and it can potentially call other contracts methods which gas cost isn't deterministic (maybe it depends on the blockchain status in that moment).
Indeed, there is no need to call other contracts, since the EVM is equivalent to a Turing machine you could build a not estimable algorithm for the halting problem.
However my previous example is more suggestive.

Instead, if you consider contracts without the constructor, I think that you're right. I don't know how it works internally but I think `estimateGas()` is exact in this case.

Comment: you are right, but we can simulate (I mean using local dev node ) all the processes before actual deployment and by deterministic I mean this part. Q: is this right? if I deploy a contract to `ganache` (or `geth`) and the deployment consume for example 1234567 unit of gas this means that It will  cost exactly this much when I deploy to main net?

Comment: I never checked but I think that in this case you will have an exact estimation, let's try! Indeed every time I deployed a contract of this type (without constructor, or anyway deterministic) I noticed that the gas limit was precise and 100% of the gas was used.